# MS Exam 70-536 - Caspol actions not presented by .Net Config Tool

Tags: .net, code-access-security, caspol

Studying MS Exam 70-536 .Net Foundation I've got to Chapter 11 Application Security and in the end of a lesson there is a practice to add code group with .Net Configuration Tool and change it with caspol.

After adding new code group with config tool I've tried to run

```
caspol -lg
```

but new group was not listed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation is that although I've been working with .Net 2.0 Configuration tool (as it suggested in book), somehow default caspol instance was .Net 1.0.

Funny it's not explained in book.

Running caspol from .Net 2.0 folder resolved the issue.